# retrieve the total likes and dislikes of a youtube channel using php

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am trying to get the total likes and dislikes of a company channel youtube using API and php but as for now I get only subscribers , total views, and total videos.Does anybody knows how can I proceed, I need to push all these informations to a DB.

```
"statistics": {
    "viewCount": "793781",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "3861",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "149"
 }
```

Comment: Check out the `getRating` endpoint in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you Magnus, actually this solution is for each video and doesnt generate the total likes/dislikes of all videos in a specific youtube channel.

Comment: Have you checked out their Reporting API? Or is that what you're using? You should add more info to your question, like which API you're using and how you make your requests (the code).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating) : you can use the `getRating` endpoint like this :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/getRating
```

And you will get somethings like this

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoGetRatingResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "items": [
    {
      "videoId": string,
      "rating": string
    }
  ]
}
```